# How to expand this floating elements to auto-fill the clearfix div

Tags: css

In an assignment, I'm trying to replicate [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhpic.png) given by the teacher with html and css, but only got [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inZNi.png)  despite trying my best.

How can I make the aside auot-fill the space nicely?

My html:

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <section>...</section>
  <aside>...</aside>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
section, aside {
  float: left;
}

section {
  width: 55%;
}

aside {
  ?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be using flexbox. In this example I turned the tables around and made the red div fill up the rest of the space by setting `max-width: 20%` (just to emphasize the effect) to the blue div it will not expand beyond that width. Naturally with `flex: 1` both divs would try to be equal width compared to the container.

```css
.clearfix {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

aside {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <section>
    asd<br />
    asd<br />
    asd<br />
    asd<br />
    asd<br />
    asd<br />
    asd<br />
    asd<br />
  </section>
  <aside>...</aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve? Apologies if I missed something. All I did was manually adjust the height, so

```
        #aside {
            width: 43%;
            float: right;
            height: 222px;
        }
```

[See my attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/cd1sbxmj/)

Comment: No, there should be a better way. The right part should auto-adjust as the left part changes